# Webp images not added srcset

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, search-engine, wordpress-featured-image

Our wordpress website using webp images as featured image.

For page speed we convert jpg or png image to webp .

Here webp images not added srcset so it causes issue in pagespeed add proper size images.

In our website jpg and png added srcset based on responsive image but srcset not working in webp images.

Why webp image not added srcset ? please help me

Answer (score 1):

Ugh - because WordPress isn't converting images to webp for you when you upload. That's how WordPress generates the srcset for jpg images, when you upload an jpg image, WordPress uses GD or ImageMagick to create new images in different sizes. But they are not doing this for webp images.

Plus, an srcset for webp images uses a  tag and not the  tag, so it is more complicated then just replacing one for the other. Many of us are struggling with this issue.